# DBCC CHECKDB Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016

No nosso cenário atual de banco de dados, temos dois banco de dados

1. Um banco de dados principal: **BANCO01**
2. E um banco de dados de dependência do BANCO01 usado para testes: **BANCO02**

Após execução do script de verificação de integridade do banco de dados.

```
DBCC CHECKDB ( BANCO01 ) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS;
```

O foi retornado a seguinte mensagem:

```
Mensagem 596, Nível 21, Estado 1, Linha 2
Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.
Mensagem 0, Nível 20, Estado 0, Linha 2
Erro grave no comando atual. Os resultados, se houver algum, deverão ser descartados.
```

Está mensagem é retornada quando qualquer script DBCC é executado.

Também verifiquei os retornos de LOG mais não entendi o porque das mensagens também.

[image: log]

O tamanho atual do **BANCO01** é de cerca de 80GB.

[image: BANCO01]

Foi executado o mesmo script no **BANCO02** e ocorreu normalmente.
Porém esse **BANCO02** tem cerca de 160 GB.

[image: BANCO02]

Nosso cenário atual de armazenamento temos cerca de 111GB Livres disponíveis.

[image: ESPACO]

Como eu poderia corrigir, para conseguir executar o DBCC CHECKDB normalmente?

Comment: esse erro pode ter muitas causas, mas pelo que colocou, eu sugiro fazer o shrink do BANCO02 e liberar o espaço antes. Lembre que o tamanho dos db/log vai dobrado (a não se que seja configurado de forma diferente), e pode ser que ele queira fazer isso para essa operação, o que precisaria de mais 160Gb. Então para resolver isso, libere os recursos primeiro e tente novamente, pq pelo que escreveu, o banco 02 deve supostamente ter o mesmo tamanho do 01